# Mathematica, Solving Complex Integral - Wrong solution

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I know that

$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{itx}}{\pi (1+x^2)}\mathrm{d}x=e^{-|t|}$$

I wanted to verify this in *Mathematica*.

The computation of

```
Integrate[Exp[I*t*x]/(Pi*(1 + x^2)), {x,-Infinity,Infinity}]
```

doesn't work.

The Integration of

```
 Integrate[ComplexExpand[Exp[I*t*x]/(Pi*(1 + x^2))], {x,-Infinity,Infinity}]
```

does.

Fair enough.

I also know that 
$\int_{0}^\infty\frac{e^{itx}}{\pi (1+x^2)}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2}e^{-|t|}$
(note the integration from 0 to $\infty$)

Again,

```
    Integrate[Exp[I*t*x]/(Pi*(1 + x^2)), {x,0,Infinity}]
```

doesn't work.

But this time,

```
      Integrate[ComplexExpand[Exp[I*t*x]/(Pi*(1 + x^2))], {x,0,Infinity}]
```

yields

```
ConditionalExpression[ 1/2 (E^-Abs[t] + (
I t MeijerG[{{0}, {}}, {{0, 0}, {-(1/2)}}, t^2/4])/(
2 Sqrt[\[Pi]])), t \[Element] Reals]
```

I'm confused of what this MeijerG want to tell me and why it is there in the first place - the second term should be zero...

Thanks already!

edit: of course, $t \in \mathrm{R}$

Comment: Have you tried `Integrate[Exp[I*t*x]/(Pi*(1 + x^2)), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> {t \[Element] Reals}]` ?

Comment: Thanks! This solves the problem with the ComplexExpand, but sadly not the second one with the MeijerG-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathematica 11.2.0.0 correctly answers

```
Integrate[Exp[I*t*x]/(Pi*(1 + x^2)), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

> ConditionalExpression[E^-Abs[t], t \ [Element] Reals]

If $\Im t \ne 0$, then the integral diverges.

```
Integrate[Exp[I*t*x]/(Pi*(1 + x^2)), {x, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> t \[Element] Reals]
```

> 1/2 (E^-Abs[t] + (
>      I MeijerG[{{1/2}, {}}, {{1/2, 1/2}, {0}}, t^2/4] Sign[t])/
>      Sqrt[[Pi]]

Let us verify it through

```
NIntegrate[Exp[I*x]/(Pi*(1 + x^2)), {x, 0, Infinity}]
```

> 0.18394 + 0.20587 I

Comment: Thanks...so there is an imaginary part i was not aware of. Then I've got to find out why it is there.

Answer (score 5):

For your first integral, you can just use [`FourierTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FourierTransform):

```
FourierTransform[Sqrt[2Pi]/(Pi(1+x^2)),x,t]
```

> E^-Abs[t]

For your second integral, what makes you think the imaginary part is 0? If you just want the real part of the integral you can use [`FourierCosTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FourierCosTransform):

```
FourierCosTransform[Sqrt[Pi/2]/(Pi(1+x^2)),x,t]
```

> E^-t/2

The factors of `Sqrt[2 Pi]` and `Sqrt[Pi/2]` are just to take care of the prefactors in the definitions of `FourierTransform` and `FourierCosTransform`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is it no zero? I have a (physically motivated) calculation in a book, where this is claimed

Comment: I can't see why it would be 0. For the integral from -Infinity to Infinity, the imaginary part is 0 since it is an odd function of x. No such symmetry argument is available for the integral from 0 to Infinity.